# Stuck on linking to a url in the database, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I tried both these:

```
<% @candidates.each do |candidate| %>
  <h4> <%=candidate.full_name %></h4>
  <p>Links: <%= link_to "facebook", "#{candidate.link1}" %> </p>
<% end %>

<% @candidates.each do |candidate| %>
  <h4> <%=candidate.full_name %></h4>
  <p>Links: <%= link_to "facebook", "candidate.link1" %> </p>
<% end %>
```

With the first one, the string interpolation, I get returned an facebook, ignoring the second part of the link_to altogether.
With the second one, where the link1 is an attribute of the class Candidate, I get an error No Route matches candidate.link1.

What syntax do I need so the second part of the link_to is seen as a url in the database (in this case: "https://facebook.com/......") instead of a route?

Comment: what is the value of `candidate.link1`

Comment: Just try `<%= link_to "facebook", candidate.link1 %>` without quotes

Comment: Sovalina is correct. Thanks